# Консольная текстовая программа на Swift 4

Tags: swift4

Пишу программу на Swift 4 консольную под MacOS 10.13.5 и почемуто знаки <,==,> являются ошибкой привожу код ошибки
Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int' вот такая ошибка выплывает везде где есть операторы, а вот сам код программы:

```
import Cocoa
import Darwin
import Foundation


var age: Int? = Int(20)
//var age = 0

if let age = readLine()
{
    if age < 5 { 
        print ("Пора идти в садик")
    } else if age == 5 {
        print ("Пора идти в прескул")
    } else if (age > 5) && (age <= 18) {
        let grade = age - 5
        print ("Пора идти в \(grade) класс")
    } else {
        print ("Пора идти в университет")
}
}
```

---

```
import Cocoa
import Darwin
import Foundation


var age: Int? = Int(20)
//var age = 0
age = readLine()
{
    if age < 5 { 
        print ("Пора идти в садик")
    } else if age == 5 {
        print ("Пора идти в прескул")
    } else if (age > 5) && (age <= 18) {
        let grade = age - 5
        print ("Пора идти в \(grade) класс")
    } else {
        print ("Пора идти в университет")
    }
}
```

Comment: И правильно всплывает. Вы как собрались сравнивать текст с числом?

Comment: И что же делать подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Я задал вам вопрос, ответ на который даст вам решение. Как вы хотите их сравнивать?

Comment: Вводить  число в readLine и оно сравнивается с age

Comment: Таким образом, вы хотите преобразовать результат `readLine()` (текст) в число.

Comment: Да age при readLine являться должно числом

Comment: Не "должно являться", а "надо преобразовать".

Comment: А как надо преобразовать я просто не знаю

Comment: Ну у меня же age превращена из String в Int var age: Int? = Int(20)

Comment: Это другой `age`. `let`'ом вы объявили новый в пределах `if`'а :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно

Comment: Я изменил код и вот что получилось теперь только одна ошибка после первой фигурной скобки Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Answer (score 0):

Первое. Swift - строго типизированный язык, поэтому нельзя не то что строку с числом сравнить, а и числа разных типов, например `Int` и `Double`.

Второе. Возможность группировать фрагменты кода фигурными `{}` скобками была до Swift 3, поэтому и возникает ошибка `Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Bool'`

Чуток подправленный Ваш пример, чтобы заработало:

```
print("Введите возраст")
guard let input = readLine(),
    let age = Int(input) else {
        print("Неверный ввод. Повторите попытку")
        exit(0)
}
if age < 5 {
    print ("Пора идти в садик")
} else if age == 5 {
    print ("Пора идти в прескул")
} else if (age > 5) && (age <= 18) {
    let grade = age - 5
    print ("Пора идти в \(grade) класс")
} else {
    print ("Пора идти в университет")
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое, всё получилось!